# What is the correct way to add installed libraries to classpath?

Tags: java, debian, classpath

In Debian, libraries you install with `apt-get install libsomething-java` go into `/usr/share/java` directory. What is the correct way to add those to the classpath of your application? IDEs (at least IDEA) don't see those libraries unless you explicitly add them to classpath. Are you supposed to add manually to your project those you need? I thought libraries installed system-wide this way would be available to your code the same way as, for example, AWT and Collections API are always available without adding them to your classpath.

**Update:**

For example, I'm using ant and I add `<fileset dir="libs" includes="**/*.jar"/>` to classpath. Would it be correct to use a library installed in my system by creating a symlink to `/usr/share/java/lib-i-need.jar` in libs directory, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add explicitly external libraries(jar-files) for your application in classpath. AWT and Collections API is the part of JavaSE, it contains in your JDK. For managment dependencies(for example jar, xml and another artifacts) read about Maven.

If in this directory contains all you need libraries, I think, it correct way.